# Export .ics file from Oulook appearing datetime in different timezone

Tags: php, icalendar

I am using icalendar in my project. There is some privilege in my application where user can generate and export .ics file and import into outlook. In outlook user can add some event and also generate .ics file and import into calendar. The issue is when user export .ics file then file contain following data:

```
  "start_datetime" => "2016-04-06 18:00:00" //UTC Time
  "end_datetime" => "2016-04-06 18:30:00"   //UTC Time
  "status" => null
  "title" => "Free"
  "description" => ""
  "from" => "Dr Demo xprt02"
```

When user imports that file into outlook, exports from outlook again and imports back into application then .ics return:

```
    array:11 [▼
        "CLASS" => "PUBLIC"
        "CREATED" => "20160405T073709Z"
        "DTEND" => "20160406T130000Z"
        "DTSTAMP" => "20160405T020700Z"
        "DTSTART" => "20160406T123000Z"
        "LAST-MODIFIED" => "20160405T073709Z"
        "SEQUENCE" => "0"
        "SUMMARY" => " Free"
        "TRANSP" => "OPAQUE"
        "UID" => "20160405T073649-31540-f4wd.com"
        "X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS" => "BUSY"
    ]
```

after converting .ics contents into php I get.

```
  "start_datetime" => "2016-04-06 12:30:00"
  "end_datetime" => "2016-04-06 13:00:00" 
  "status" => null
  "title" => "Free"
  "description" => ""
  "from" => "Dr Demo xprt02"
```

I don't know why there is such a difference in `startdatetime` and `end_datetime` after getting same file from outlook. I think outlook is not returning in UTC. If someone have any idea then please share.

Comment: You have to show ics contents, not the converted php. Surely there is a timezone issue.

Comment: First of all, I sugest you to compare real ics files (text files, open it with a basic text editor (See [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125338/calendar-ical-ics-format) to example format), then verify with an original ics file (not created by your program), import it on outlook and then export it to see if the behavior is the same. Then you can realize if the problem is from your script or from outlook.

Comment: @fusion3k, I already done that. Some column like "CLASS" => "PUBLIC, X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS etc" I used in my script after refering from .ics file(export from outlook).

Comment: I don't think that we can find a solution by this method. The raw file has not arrays, it is something like "BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:...". You have to investigate if file produced by you is correct following [ics tech specs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar#Core_object). Also can be useful to see your code and to know what library do you use to produce ics files

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.

```
$ics =  "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n";
$ics .= "PRODID:-//F4WD TM//NONSGML F4WD//EN\n";
$ics .= "VERSION:2.0\n";
$ics .= "CALSCALE:GREGORIAN\n";
$ics .= "METHOD:PUBLISH\n"; // requied by Outlook
$ics .= "X-WR-CALNAME:\n";
$ics .= "TZ:+00:\n";
$ics .= "BEGIN:VEVENT\n";
$ics .= "CLASS:PUBLIC\n";
$ics .= "CREATED:".date('Ymd', strtotime($v['start_datetime'])).'T'.date('His', strtotime($v['start_datetime']))."Z\n"; 
$ics .= "DTEND;TZID=UTC:".date('Ymd', strtotime($v['end_datetime'])).'T'.date('His', strtotime($v['end_datetime']))."Z\n"; 
$ics .= "DTSTAMP:".date('Ymd').'T'.date('His')."Z\n"; 
$ics .= "DTSTART;TZID=UTC:".date('Ymd', strtotime($v['start_datetime'])).'T'.date('His', strtotime($v['start_datetime']))."\n";
$ics .= "LAST-MODIFIED:".date('Ymd', strtotime($v['start_datetime'])).'T'.date('His', strtotime($v['start_datetime']))."\n"; 
$ics .= "SEQUENCE: 0\n";
$ics .= "SUMMARY: ".$v['title']. "\n";
$ics .= "TRANSP:OPAQUE \n";
$ics .= "UID:".date('Ymd').'T'.date('His')."-".rand()."-".$domain_url."\n"; 
$ics .= "DESCRIPTION:".$v['description']."\n";
$ics .= "X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY".$v['status']."\n";
$ics .= "END:VEVENT\n";
$ics .= "END:VCALENDAR\n";
```

I was not using **;TZID=UTC** with **DTSTART** and **DTEND**. So now all working fine.